# Blender 3.3 crashing instantly to desktop randomly

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface, gpu, wireframe

For a couple of years now, Blender has been crashing instantly to the desktop due to seemingly random actions in the non-rendered viewport with just a matcap. Actions, such as panning or orbiting the view, moving some geometry in edit mode, switching to wireframe view, adjusting sliders, UV unwrapping, or basically any action you might do when modelling has at some point caused instant crashes.

The main commonality I can suggest is that I am usually doing high poly modelling, but often it will still crash with hidden or isolated objects with modifiers disabled. Crashes can also occur multiple times over a short time span, occasionally within a few minutes of each other.

Due to the nature of the crashes, no normal crash dump file can be created. Additionally, this issue also appears capable of crashing the entire computer instantly, resulting in a black screen that requires the power button to shut down, no logs can be created in this instance either.

My system is reasonably powerful:

Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070
AMD Ryzen 7 2700
64GB RAM
1TB SSD

Multiple tests using OCCT have been conducted to max out the CPU, GPU, RAM, and I have even done these tests while modelling, watching videos and browsing simultaneously with no crash.

Most of the addons I have enabled are with Blender by default, the exception being Edge Flow

So far, I have been able to get a debug log from during a crash using the blender_debug_gpu.cmd in the Blender file which I can provide.

At the moment, I'm looking for any information on what this could be, what's causing it, anything to narrow down the problem.

**Update to add**:

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64bit (Version 21H2, OS Build 19044.2006)
GPU Driver: Version 517.48 (released 27th September 2022)

I've done a clean reinstall of the GPU drivers using DDU, the crashes are still occurring. This problem has been happening for approximately the last 2 years, across multiple versions and computer installations.

Comment: If Blender is able to crash the operating system, then the problem is unlikely to be Blender. Just my guess.

Comment: It might be useful to explicitly state the GPU Memory.  You have already listed hardware.  The info panel in Blender has an option to list info related to the GPU.  You may want to list that as well.  Does the problem decrease when you have a fresh start on the machine with a minimum of competing software applications?

Comment: Hi, the GPU memory is GDDR6 (Micron), 8192MB, Bus Width 256bit, 1750MHz. Also, it's a good point that Blender probably wouldn't be the cause, but it seems to happen only when I use Blender. The System crash is also quite rare, I've only had a couple instances of it ever.

Comment: Do you have these issues in previous versions? Try Blender 2.93. It has similar features and is very stable. Blender 2.93 didn't crash once for me in 6 months of use. I upgraded to 3.3 and now I get roughly 1 crash every 10 minutes.